# Java interface to Windows communications? (OLE, OPC, DDE)

Tags: java, windows, ole, dde

I need to integrate an off-the-shelf Windows application with a Java application.  At a few key points, I need the Windows application to send an "event" and some data to the Java application.

The Windows application anticipated this need, and can be configured to "Poke a DDE Item", "Set an OLE Auto-Property" or "Write an OPC Item".

I'm already using [JACOB](http://jacob-project.wiki.sourceforge.net/) to call COM methods and set COM properties on a COM object.  However, I'm guessing that's pretty unrelated to these "event" notification capabilities.

Anyone have any experience calling FROM a Windows application to a "DDE Item", "OLE Auto-Property" or "OPC Item" that's actually in a JVM?

Any pointers, advice, etc, would be appreciated.

Comment: already looked at? http://www.nevaobject.com/_docs/_javadde/JavaDde.htm
works in both ways (client and server)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access OPC Servers, the [OpenSCADA - Utgard](http://www.openscada.org/) Project might just be what you need.

Itself it uses [j-interop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-interop/) to access COM.

If you need any help, just drop a line to Juergen DOT Rose AT inavare DOT net

http://www.openscada.org/